# iOS development Animating Table view custom cell content

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, tableview

I am working on new application and i would like to have custom table view. I need to have cell that have 2 labels 1 check box and 2 buttons. The problem i have is that 2 buttons need to be shown only if user press edit button on top. I made all this to work but i have some problem with reusable cells or something like that.

I made custom cell class so i can assign data to it.

First state is: First state on img

Then when user press edit button on top i need everyting to animate and come to right place.
I want text to animate to right to make space for button, delete button needs to come animated from left side and edit butom to come in animated from right side.

This is what i want to get after animations are done: Second state on img

I made all this to work but now i have problem that first 2 cells that will come on screen after i scroll down are not effected by my code :(

This is what i get: Third state on img

i will post my project code here and if some1 can help me with it i would be more then thrilled. I point me to right way to do this.

Code downoald: https://www.mediafire.com/?g1g6d7h33mpkyt7

and i will post some code here that i think is crucial to my problem:

for animations i use:

```
[cell.infoView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, CGRectGetMinY(cell.infoView.frame), CGRectGetWidth(cell.infoView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(cell.infoView.frame))];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                              delay:0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{
                             [cell.infoView setFrame:CGRectMake(70, CGRectGetMinY(cell.infoView.frame), CGRectGetWidth(cell.infoView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(cell.infoView.frame))];
                         }
                         completion:nil];
```

for cell init i use:

```
CICustomCell *cell;
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];
if(cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HCICustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

cell.itemName = [dwarves objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.quantity = 25.99;
```

for table init i use:

```
UITableView *tableView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1];

tableView.rowHeight = 60;

UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"HCICustomCell"
                            bundle:nil];


[tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];
```

img: http://i270.photobucket.com/albums/jj109/lazardj/scsimg.jpg~original

EDIT:

I also tried something now. If i start my activity then scroll down a bit so i get some new cells i dont have this problem. So it must be something with creating cells or reusability of cells or something like that. I am new to ios development so i cant figure this out on my own :( so please help :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `cellForRow` function in your tableview delegate you need to deal with the location of your labels.  So every time you request a new (or reused) cell you need to check whether you are in edit mode and then set the labels frames accordingly.

It appears as you are already doing this for the buttons, as they show up in the proper place, but the labels are being re-used at their initial locations (when they were released by the tableview).

Comment: I am doing that:

if(!firstInit && !doNotAnimate)
    {
        
        if(editSelected)
        {
animations goes here.
}
}

the thing with buttons showing on right place is that they are placed there in xib file. If you look at my project you have full code and you can see that i am doing all i can to move label with 
[cell.infoView setFrame:CGRectMake(70, CGRectGetMinY(cell.infoView.frame), CGRectGetWidth(cell.infoView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(cell.infoView.frame))]; but its not effecting it :(

Comment: Continue... How do you set the cell.infoView.frame?  Or do you?

Comment: I think there is some problem when you try to change cell appearance in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. It show me all data as they need to me but it will not allow me to change position of labels and things like that. I am not sure if i am doing something wrong but this is some wierd problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look at your project, and the problem appears to stem from using AutoLayout. The automatic constraints appear to be interfering with your view layouts. If you go to your `HCICustomCell.xib` file and click on the file inspector tab, you'll see a checkbox for "**Use Autolayout**". Uncheck this and then set the auto-resizing constraints manually for each view in the Size Inspector tab. I've uploaded a revised version of your project [here](http://www.filedropper.com/testsltabela).

Comment: I tried your solution but i still get bugs in some cases. so i did it on kinda stupid but working way :) you can see my post what i did :) Still thanks for your time and info about auto layout

Comment: What kind of bugs were you getting? Seemed to work fine for me.

Comment: if you try 10 or 20 times to move up down turn edit on edit off some cells get bugged. like you have all cells with edit and delete button showing and 1 that does not have them on. its random when it will happen. i cant figure it out to tell you on what combination it does happen :) i can make you photo with ti bugged if you want.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

I done some more work on this. Tried solutions you provided me but there are still times when it gets bugged so i came with my own one. I figured out that the problem is that you cant move view in cell on first init but you can show hide them. So i decided to try to make same info view on place where it needs to be when enable is on. When enable is off its hidden and when enable is on it shows up. This is what fixed my problem :) I know its not the smartest way to do things but i managed to do what i wanted and its not messing performances of application.

This is project with fixed bugs. If any1 want can use it :)

Thanks for all your time and suggestions.

Project: https://www.mediafire.com/?uhatbh8c20xu49v